# Laravel arbitary set exit status code to custom command

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface, laravel-5.7

I am implementing the following custom command for running a background processes:

```php
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Model\MyModel;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class MyCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = "Doing StuffyStuff";

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = "mycommand:dostuff";

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle(MyModel $model): void
    {
        //@todo Implement Upload
        try {
            $model->findOrFail(12);
            //Set Exit Status Code 0
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //Set status code 1
        }
    }


}
```

So as you can see I want to specify the statuc code depending if an exception has been thrown or not. If success I want to use exit status code 0 and if fail I want to use exit status code 1 as Unix Spec specifies.

So do you have any Idea how to do that?

Comment: What do you excellently want to achieve ?

Comment: What I want to achieve is when an exception is thrown to make the command exit a exit status code 1, as part of the exception handling.

Comment: Add $status into try and cache block with exist status code and catch into finally block and do whatever you want to do in finally block.

Comment: My questions is How do you return into the console the desired exit status code. Usually In linux system a running command returns an exit status code. In my case it is the custom artisan command.

Comment: how about when it success "return 0;"

otherwise, return 1;

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas If you really want to make your code standard I would recommend to use php standard constant for output https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can return the code wherever you want

```
public function handle(MyModel $model): int
    {
        //@todo Implement Upload
        try {
            $model->findOrFail(12);
            return 0;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->error($e->getMessage());
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

You can see an example & explain [here](https://laravel-news.com/custom-artisan-commands)

Comment: It's better to use constants like `Command::SUCCESS` (0) or `Command::FAILURE` (1) instead of "magic" numbers.

Comment: Well these number are well defined as POSIX status codes. https://shapeshed.com/unix-exit-codes/